# Undefined method each for Rack::Flash::FlashHash

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm using  `rack-flash3` gem in my Sinatra app. I have a partial called _flash. I try to do the following there

```
.row-fluid
  .flash-notice
     - flash.each do |type, message|
      .alert{class: ".alert-#{type}"}
        %button.close{type: "button", "data-dismiss" => "alert"}x
        = message
```

and it gives me the error of "`undefined method each for Rack::Flash::FlashHash`"

So how I iterate through `flash` to achieve what I want?

Comment: It looks like you [cant](https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash/blob/master/lib/rack/flash.rb). I think that's a really poor way to implement something that should talk like a Hash, but that's just my opinion. Their example shows to do something like `[:error, :notice].each { |key| flash[key] }` ...

Comment: Where did you see the example?

Comment: The link in my previous comment is the `FlashHash` class, it doesn't implement a normal enumerable interface, as I believe it should